# Saving magento qty to quote

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have a custom quantity which I insert into the sales_flat_quote table with this code:

```
    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    $item = $quote->getItemById($itemID);
    $item->setQty((double) $qty);
```

The above code works fine but it affects my custom price which sets back to the magento price after I save.

I currently have my code placed in the view shopping cart page which may be what is causing the problem. Where can I place my code so that the qty updates at the onestepcheckout page instead?

Comment: After this code you are saving the whole quote or saving the item only?...my guess is when you are saving at that time it calls `collectTotals()` function which sets back the product value. Can you add more code please.

Comment: At the end i use $quote->save();

Comment: Do not save the quote. Just save the item. If you save the quote it will call `collectTotals()` function which will override your pricing.

Comment: changed to $item->save() and get same result

Comment: Now i simply have  $_item->setQty((double) $quantity); 
      $_item->save();

Comment: still same result

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you want to update the quantity of a specific product if a customer added it to the cart.

> Method 01 : When you know the **product ID** to be updated

```
$qty = 4;
$productId = 125;

// get quote
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();

// check if product is in the cart
if($quote->hasProductId($productId)) {
    //get Product 
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

    //get Item
    $item = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);
    $quote->getCart()->updateItem(array($item->getId()=>array('qty'=>$qty)));
    $quote->getCart()->save();
}
```

> Method 02 : When you know the **item ID** to be updated

```
$qty = 4;
$itemId = 175;

// get quote
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$item = $quote->getItemById($itemId);
$quote->updateItem($itemId, array( 'qty' => $qty));
$quote->save();
```